# What are some design patterns to handle when the domain object changes but the database hasn't?

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, entity, domain-driven-design

Consider the following Enum:

```
enum Size{
  SMALL,
  MIDDLE,
  LARGE
}
```

which we will save to the database using its `toString` method. Now later on we decide to change `MIDDLE` to `MEDIUM`. But we are unable to update the database, so now we will have a mixture of `MIDDLE` and `MEDIUM` values stored.

What are some design patterns to handle this transformation java?

Comment: Something on database layer(persistence layer). While fetching the data there should be  a condition that converts MEDIUM to MIDDLE. Then above layers will be considering that data as MIDDLE so you will be able to use that enum.

Comment: One option can be to override the enum `toString` for `MIDDLE` and `MEDIUM` to print the same value. In general try to avoid changes for purely visual reasons, as now all of your code needs to be updated to encapsulate this information. I would probably leave the database alone (keep storing as middle) and only expose the name change at very high levels such as GUI tools. If you really do want to change this value in db, the change should be made at the data layer like @memoricab describes, either with a backfill of the data or with a conversion operation transparent to the calling clients.

Comment: @flakes option also nice. But then you should not use name() method for that enum anymore and refactor usages. Because you are supposed to override also name() method to apply same operation as toString() but you can't override name() method.

Comment: @flakes so that's exactly what I want to do, but I'm not sure of a "nice" way to do it. Where do I put this transformer? Maybe just in the DAO class? Is there a standard DDD way of handling this?

Comment: @james you could just add a constructor to the enum that takes its toString value as an argument. Then override the appropriate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Enums represent constants in java programs. So ideally they shouldn't be altered.
But still if you have a requrement/usecase where you cannot avoid this, there is a cleaner way to do this.

Consider below code:

```
public enum Size {
    SMALL("SMALL"),
    MEDIUM("MIDDLE"),
    LARGE("LARGE");

    String dbName;
    Size(String dbName) {
        this.dbName = dbName;
    }

    public String getDbName() {
        return dbName;
    }
}
```

Calling function:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Size.MEDIUM.toString());
        System.out.println(Size.MEDIUM.getDbName());
    }
}
```

But for this you have to replace `toString` to `getDbName()` in persistence layers.

Output:

```
MEDIUM
MIDDLE
```